# My CSS file won't link and I don't know why

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to link p1.css to p1.html, but for some reason it's not working. It's in a file on my desktop called 115, and in a file inside called css, but no matter what I add or take away it won't show up. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>CIS 115 - Project 1</title>
<p lang="en"></p>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="Project 1" content="">
<meta name="Kim Peoples" content="Kim Peoples">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="115/css/p1.css">
<script src="115/p1/p1.js"> </script>
</head>
```

this is the css, which is I'm in the process of making but I want to make sure it links first.

```
body {
background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: I think you mistakenly input/include the `<p>` tag inside your head...

Comment: @iMarkDesigns I tried changing that and it didn't work.

Comment: @KimPeoples, your `css` file path might be wrong/inaccessible. Your code works fine for me. Post your `css` content too, if possible

Comment: @Prabhakar huh? or you mean Kim Peoples...?

Comment: I've added the css, but I'm still working on it. The html file is based on a template we use in the class, so I'm not sure why it's not working.  @Prabhakar

Comment: @KimPeoples no, you cannot add color property to head tag element. I am not sure where did you get that. But i think it is wrong.

Comment: Please show your directory structure, namely where your `index.html` file is located. Is it inside of the folder called "115"?

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming that you are viewing/accessing your file via desktop. Though not clearly sure if you are using localhost server or not. Here's what I think what was your file tree flow..

```
/115
-/css
 -- p1.css
-/p1
 -- p1.js
- index.html
```

Then in your HTML, it should look like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>CIS 115 - Project 1</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Kim Peoples - CIS 115 Project">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/p1.css">
  <script src="p1/p1.js"> </script>
</head>
```

**Note:** Since you are initiating the index inside your 115 folder, you don't have to include 115 folder to your internal files. Just simple append the folders of your media files and CSS/JS files.

Answer (score 0):

- first you have to press ctrl + u on browser window and check css path
  has been coming or not? after click it css will be display properly
  or not ?
- if still issue then check with inspect element in browser. press f12
  in browser window.

  still issue then you can use element property in !important; in css
  code

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try ../115/css/p1.css? 
Seems like your absolute path is incorrect. 
Here is a link to more information about absolute paths and relative paths:
[Absolute vs Relative Pathlinks](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/)

Hopefully this is helpful to you.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Your link is broken and for some reason I can't edit it.

Comment: @Josh. Yes, sorry this is my first time using this website.